# Client_ID value is now snowflake

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord.js

I am trying to invite my Discord.js bot to a server but whenever I use the URL, it says CLIENT_ID "(my client ID is in here)" is not snowflake.

What does this mean, I've looked about but haven't seen any fixes to this problem. My redirect URI is `https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?&client_id=[CLIENTID]&scope=bot` with CLIENTID as my client ID. I'm not fully sure on how to use a redirect URI properly, as for my other bot(in python) I didn't need it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, for me it turns out my client id ended up having a semicolon at the end because Prettier auto-appended it to my .env file.

Try printing out your client ID and make sure it's just a string of numbers like this

```
CLIENT_ID = "123456789876543210"
```

with no other characters in it

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the ID you substituted into the URL, double check the ID you provided is right and corresponds to the bot; if this turns up okay, I would recommend generating an invite URL through the Discord developer portal.

If you navigate to the [**Discord Developer Portal**](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and click on the application you want to invite (your discord.js bot) it will open the application's page. From there click `OAuth2` on the side panel then `URL Generator` and select the scopes and permissions you want for the bot and Discord will generate the URL for you.

On a side note, the programming library or language you use will have not affect on the invite link.

Comment: I am sure the Client ID is correct(I have tried it many times), but it still says it's not snowflake. In the URL generator it says it requires a redirect URI and does not show me the invite link for the bot.

Comment: What scopes are you selecting? If you are unsure what they are or what they do, I recommend using using `bot` and `application.commands` and the URL will appear at the bottom.

Comment: Even with only bot and applications.commands selected, it still shows 'Please enter a redirect uri' at the bottom where the URL is meant to show up.